# Read the contents of a .csv file in Google Drive

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api, read.csv

I have a public .csv file on my Google Drive and I want to pull the file and display it in my flutter app. I figured that I need the fileID, the OAuth token and the client ID,I already got these. I also have a fully working sign-in page. But I can't figure out what is the exact methodology of fetching the file. I know that there is some content of this exact question online, I am a beginner, those posts were old, and some functions were  deprecated, I couldn't understand them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the export api to get this

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]/export?mimeType=[mimeType]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]"
```

Refer https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export for more details

Please note that is restricted to 10 Mb per file

**Edit**

add these dependencies

```
dependencies:
  googleapis: any
  google_sign_in: any
```

Implement google signing

```
final googleSignIn = signIn.GoogleSignIn.standard(scopes: [drive.DriveApi.DriveScope]);
  final signIn.GoogleSignInAccount account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
```

Create a firebase project and enable google signin and link it with your project. Download its Json and add it to the project too.

Goto [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and enable Google Drive API

After the login is complete you can use the download method to download the file

```
Future<File> download(String id, String filename, {Function(int, int) onDownloadProgress});
```

Check this tutorial for reference
https://betterprogramming.pub/the-minimum-guide-for-using-google-drive-api-with-flutter-9207e4cb05ba

Comment: thank you for the response.. what would the code be, in my flutter app?

Comment: It is an api. You can add it just like how you write an api call. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get

Comment: @ Kaushik Chandru, I viewed the links that you mentioned in this post, but I didn't get much info about how to implement this in code. Please help me how to do this.